# What type of insect is this?

Tags: entomology

[image: myst![mystery bug]ery bug 1][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKRQO.jpg)

What insect are these? Found them indoors. No wings, just crawling on the walls.

Comment: Where was the photo taken (geographically), at what time of the year, and how large are they (can you include a scale bar in the photo)? All will be useful for answering this question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a termite; male; after loss of wings.

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining why you think so - for example find a picture of a male termite with its wings and explain what body parts you compare with the insect in the photo to reach that conclusion.

Comment: Thick waist, straight antennae, head position are all consistent with a male termite.

Comment: Edit your answer to include that and provide a reference or picture for the question author to check up themselves and I would say this is a perfectly sufficient answer :)